# Cannot map subchildren of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My file structure has a `questions` array, in which there's one more `section_questions` array I want to access.

The React code looks like this

```
<div className="questions-container">
  {employee.questions.map(question => (
    <p className="section-title">{question.section_name}</p>

    /* This won't work, syntax error */
    { question.section_questions.map(sq => ( <p>Yo</p> )) }

    )
  )}
</div>
```

JSON-Object:

```
"questions": [
      {
        "section_name": "Random",
        "section_questions": [
          {
            "question": "Q1",
            "answer": "A1"
          },
          {
           "question": "Q2",
            "answer": "A2"
          }
        ]
      }
]
```

Why won't this work? How can I fix this?

The error is `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

Comment: can you paste some sample data of questions array. So that it will be easier to find the cause

Comment: And also your error

Comment: @Saphire Please post the error, and the questions array.

Comment: I suspect you'll find the answer to your question here: [*Dynamically access object property using variable*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) but I can't be 100% sure without, as the others have said, an example of the data and the text of the error.

Comment: I provided more details. @GangadharGandi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you need a tag (or fragment) that encloses everything underneath.

So you could:

- move the < /p> to be after `{ question.section_questions.map(sq => ( <p>Yo</p> )) }` .
- Or enclose everything in a `div`.
- Or use  a react fragment `< React.Fragment>< React.Fragment/>` instead of `div`. Suggested by: @Antoan Elenkov

See:  [reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

**Example:**

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.questions = [

        { section_name: "Learn JavaScript", section_questions: [1] },
        { section_name: "Learn React", section_questions: [1] },
        { section_name: "Play around in JSFiddle", section_questions: [1] },
        { section_name: "Build something awesome", section_questions: [1] }

    ];


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Todos:</h2>

  {this.questions.map(question => (
    <p className="section-title">
    {question.section_name}
    {question.section_questions}
    {question.section_questions.map(sq => ( <p>Yo</p> ))}
    </p>   


    )
  )}
</div>

    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/opy9k5hr/

### Update

Another option is to enclose everything in a `<div>` tag.

```
  {this.questions.map(question => (
     <div>
    <p className="section-title"> {question.section_name} </p>

    {question.section_questions}
    {question.section_questions.map(sq => ( <p>Yo</p> ))}
   </div>   


    )
  )}
```

Comment: Why? I want those to be separated <p> tags?

Comment: @Saphire Try enclosing the section with a 'div'. I have updated my answer.

Comment: So use react fragment <></> then instead of <div></div> - https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: @Antoan Elenkov I added your suggestion to my answer. Thanks!